# Interview Puzzle - Why should we override hashCode and equals methods

Tags: java, memory-management, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I had an interview and interviewer has asked one question

**Interviewer -** Why should we override hashCode and equals method for a class, if we are going to use this class's object as HashMap key.

**Me -**  I have told him the complete flow. How HashMap uses hashcode and equals methods internally (Bucket logic).

but he was not satisfied with my answer.He told me that this is the basic use only and you have perfectly explained it, but I wanna know its advanced importance not basic (He has given me some clue too - it helps in memory management) .

I have searched on internet but I did not get the answer.

Is there any other importance too? If yes what is it?

A link/document will b highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This is pretty vague; you want to know *something* about HashMaps?

Comment: Memory management? I wonder what this could mean.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Of course it's vague if OP knew what the interviewer actually meant, there wouldn't be a question at all :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't want to know about HashMaps. I wanna know how hashcode and equals method are responsible for memory management in HashMap.How hashmap uses hashcode internally that i know, but is there any other use too?

Comment: @biziclop even I dnt know wht actually he want to know :(

Comment: @AnkitSharma I struggle to think of anything. If you have a `hashCode()` implementation that returns a constant value, your `HashMap` turns into a rather ineffective linked list but you probably  know that. Another thing I can think of is if you don't override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, everything will be done on object identity, so if you insert two objects that have the same fields, both will be added, consuming more memory, but that's fairly obvious and not very relevant anyway.

Comment: @biziclop Yes, I have explained this too and told him that it is not required to override even but in this case you won't get desired result. But I was completely stuck over there.

Answer (score 1):

This might help? (Taken from http://apmblog.compuware.com/2011/12/15/the-top-java-memory-problems-part-2/)

> Incorrect implementation of equal and hashcode
>
> The relationship between the hashcode method and memory problems is
>   not obvious at first glance. However, if we consider where the
>   hashcode method is of high importance this becomes clearer.
>
> The hashcode and equals methods are used within hash maps to insert
>   and find objects based on their key. However, if the implementation of
>   the operator is faulty, existing entries are not found and new ones
>   keep being added.
>
> While the collection responsible for the memory problem can be
>   identified very quickly, it may be difficult to determine why the
>   problem occurs.

Comment: Sure, if you have a bug, bad stuff might happen!

Comment: I dont really know how HashMap internally works in java. But let's say i want to implement my own HashMap, by writing my own hash function. Initially, I consider keys be between 0 and 1000. If Hash values are distributed (nearly) uniformly by using a good hash function, I could say that there will be a very low number of collisions for a load factor < 0.80. When I reach this load factor, I double the size of the hash. But this would rather have something to do with execution time, not memory usage. . .

Comment: @DeiAndrei The problem is different here, it's a genuine memory leak situation. If you rely on the default `eq/hc` implementation, your map will use object identity. But this means that if you lose the reference to a key (say you serialize and deserialize your key object), there's no way to remove the entry from the map apart from iterating across it. This will mean that your key/value objects will never be garbage collected, except when the map itself is.

Comment: As Oli already mentioned a bug is always a bad thing. The complete article points out (indirectly) that the `equals() and `hashCode()` implementation did not adhere to the contract that an object which equals another object has to retrn the same hashCode. Therefore as long as I adhere to the contract there should be no problem. Not adhrering to the contract is clearly a bug therefore buggy software cause problems (even when overwriting methods).

Comment: @UwePlonus That's a rather simplistic view of things and has nothing to do with the question itself. The question was about the potential effects of the bug, which are important to know.